# How to create a button validation in oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am sorry for the silly question but I want to add a confirmation on an Apex button so that the dynamic action only triggers after the confirmation has been confirmed by the user.
The dynamic action is PL/SQL code so that I cant use a Javascript condition which would start a function.
So i tried using the alert/confirmation function but those dont stop the dynamic action from triggering.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

If dynamic action runs some PL/SQL code, I presume that it can be moved into a process.

Anyway: suppose that button name is `P1_BTN`

- button's Action should be "Redirect to URL"
- code used would be

  ```
  javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure?')){doSubmit('P1_BTN');}
  ```
- when you run the page and push the button and answer "yes", `P1_BTN` will submit and process related to it (according to process' Server side condition's "When button pressed" condition set to `P1_BTN`) will run.

Comment: Sorry its my bad for not beeing precise. Is it possible to do it over a dialogue without the redirect? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thanks again, just gonna use the redirect then.